# Facebook API get user EMAIL not working in the latest SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

it seems that Facebook canceled the ability to retrieve the user email, non of the SDK versions can do this anymore, at least for me after testing many of them.

I'm working on a "Register with Facebook" button, and this is what i started with:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once('Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxx');

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://xxxx/facebook/login-callback.php' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=email' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

  // print data
  echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email')) .     '">Login</a>';
}

?>
```

After printing the data:

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object ( [backingData:protected] => Array ( [id] => xxxxxxxxxx ) )
```

Email is not retrieved.

Comment: No, this is still possible. Either the user did not grant the permission, or the email address is not verified. (And in same rare edge cases, there are supposedly also some privacy settings that prevent an app from access the email, even if the user grants the permission.)

Comment: No, i'm sure that the permission of using the email is granted, and the email account is verified! I tried 2 facebook accounts, both of them did not return the email address, although it was working before.

Comment: Make a debug output of the access token used, and put it through the FB debug tool (or request `/me/permissions`), and see if the `email` permission is really granted.

Comment: OK i did, Valid :True,
Origin:Web,
Scopes:email, public_profile

See?

Comment: Not sure if you are using `FacebookRequest` here correctly. Have you tried passing the fields as 4th parameter? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/4.0.0#overview (Btw., I’d recommend switching the the SDK version 5, with that you don’t need to use the `FacebookRequest` class for simple stuff like this, but can use the `get` method of the main `Facebook` object directly.)

Comment: I tried that too, the email field returned empty after i used $object->getProperty('email'); this is weird!

Comment: Test your request in Graph API Explorer (select your app, and copy&paste your access token) – if you get the email there, when requesting `/me?fields=email`, then it is a problem with your code.

Comment: Ok, I did that, it only returned the account ID!

Comment: Plus a debug message says: "    The email field was not returned. This may be because the email was missing, invalid or hasn't been confirmed." it is returned on every account I test on it! they are all confirmed and fully active!

Comment: You can test it yourself here: http://weeesab.com/includes/facebook/login-callback.php . The second line after authenticating will return the access token for you, debug it and see the result yourself please.

Comment: Just tested it – and it works perfectly fine, requesting `/me?fields=email` with that access token returns my email address I use on Facebook.

Comment: Yes, it worked. the problem was with the accounts I tried with them, I used an old account and the email appears, this is very weird how could facebook keep our accounts working for this long time without the email is verified! how could we create those account without verifying the them anyway! i'm sure I did verified them and added verified phone numbers, but I did not know why it didn't work with them anyway.

than you for your kind help.